# AppleTV 3rd Gen Displaying 'static' randomly

Tags: appletv, hdmi, television

We have a third generation AppleTV that has just started giving us trouble (after moving - although the unit was properly packed and transported, so I do not expect damage from this).

Randomly when using various apps, the device will show what I would reference as static. The entire screen does this. The audio usually continues fine. Sometimes it gets so bad, that the TV will act like the input was dropped as well.

Connections seem ok. Rebooting the unit (unplugging power) seems to stop it for a while. It may be using a new/different HDMI cable, but I have not swapped that out to see if it makes a difference. I did reseat all cables though.

What would cause the device to do this? Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, static on the HDMI link can be as a result of too much noise (the signal to noise reason is to low). You say you have not changed the cable, that would be my first suspect.

Change that up and take it from there. Any breaks or wear on the cable and pins can introduce noise such that the signal effectively drops out.